# Symfony2 Data transformer on a Choice field type

Tags: jquery, forms, symfony, fieldtype

I am going step by step with the [How to use Data Transformers](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#model-and-view-transformers)

The problem is that what if I want to do this with a Choice type? Which I dynamically populate with jQuery?

I tested the example they provide (without creating a custom type..) and it works 100% with the text field type, but as soon as I change it to choice and give it empty choices it doesn't work, does this have to do with me populating the choices with jQuery after the page is loaded?

Example

**Model** [Select with the Model entity loaded with the query builder and Entity field type...]

**Number** [Empty choice at first, when the Model changes I make an AJAX request for the Numbers of that Model]

If I leave the Number as a text field and I manually type a valid number (looking at the database) it works, but if I leave it to jQuery and a Choice type it returns a form error with an invalid value for the Model.

In both cases I'm doing print_r($request->request) before handling the form and in both cases it submits Number => 1 which is correct in this example, but somehow it's not transforming the data when its type is Choice but when its Text it does.

This is how jQuery is populating the data for the Number select box:

```
<option value=”1”>1234ABCDEFG</option>
```

Btw, I'm transforming with the Id, which would be the value of the option selected.

Comment: Instead of leaving the choices empty in your form builder, go ahead and add on option with a value of 1.  You can have your javascript delete all the options and replace with the dynamic ones.  I suspect posting with a value one 1 will now work.  I think the choice element is validating the option value.  If this works then I have an idea of how to fix it.

Comment: Hmm, this is weird, if I add an option ,'choice', array('choices'=>array("1"=>"Test") in the builder it works but just if I don't make the ajax request, if I go ahead and trigger the request and the list gets refreshed it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok I know what the problem is now, it seems it won't transform data that wasn't previously declared in the 'choices' attribute, I went ahead and made the AJAX request and when the list got refreshed I used inspect element to search for the option with the value 1 (which is the same value as the one im the choices array called "Test") and hitted submit and it worked. what do you think @Cerad ?

Comment: I ended up loading all the Numbers with the query builder (and changing from Choice type to Entity type) and at doc ready I triggered the change event for the Model so that it refreshes the Numbers, not the best solution but for now it will do, let me know if you have a better solution. Thanks for the idea!!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok.  What you need to do is to listen to the preSubmit form event and then basically accept the submitted value by adding it to your choice element.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data

=======================================================

I didn't look at your paste bin but here is an example that seems to work for me.  It's a simple gender choice list to which I add another option client side.  The preSubmit listener simply replaces the default gender choice options with an option containing whatever was submitted.  You should be able to add in data transform stuff and be good to go.

```
namespace Cerad\Bundle\TournBundle\Form\Type\Test;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactoryInterface;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class DynamicFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function getName() { return 'cerad_tourn_test_dynamic'; }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('gender', 'choice', array(
            'choices'   => array('m' => 'Male', 'f' => 'Female'),
            'required'  => false,
        ));
        $builder->addEventSubscriber(new DynamicFormListener($builder->getFormFactory()));
    }
}
class DynamicFormListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $factory;

    public function __construct(FormFactoryInterface $factory)
    {
        $this->factory = $factory;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT   => 'preSubmit',
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData',
        );
    }
    public function preSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        // Don't need
        return;
    }
    public function preSubmit(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $gender = $data['gender'];
        if (!$gender) return; // If nothing was actually chosen

        $form = $event->getForm();

        /* =================================================
         * All we need to do is to replace the choice with one containing the $gender value
         * Once this is done $form->isValid() will pass
         *
         * I did attempt to just add the option to the existing gender choice 
         * but could not see how to do it.  
         * $genderForm = form->get('gender'); // Returns a Form object
         * $genderForm->addNewOptionToChoicesList ???
         * 
         * Might want to look up 'whatever' but that only comes into play
         * if the form fails validation and you paas it back to the user
         * You could also use client side javascript to replace 'whatever' with the correct value
         */
        $form->add($this->factory->createNamed('gender','choice', null, array(
            'choices'   => array($gender => 'whatever'),
            'required'  => false,
            'auto_initialize' => false,
        )));
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried a lot to deal with Form Events, at the PreSubmit event can you give an example of how I would add a custom option to an existent field? their documentation isn't that much helpful(for example, $this->customizeForm() ... idk what it does..), because I decided to use Data Transformers because I wasn't able to modify the data of the form and succeed with it. If you can provide a small example to guide me that would be great :)

Thank you!!!

Comment: I don't have one handy but maybe later.  However, you should be able to use your existing data transformer setup with no changes.  In PRE_SUBMIT, $event->getData() returns the raw data submitted by the user.  So you will have a number.  All you should need to do is to add this number as an option to your choice field so it passes validation.  Everything else should work just the way it does when you use a text input.

Comment: ok right now I went ahead and created the event listener and I am in the preSubmit event

$data = $event->getData();
$number = $data['Numbers'];
// get the actual Number entity with the EM
$form = $event->getForm();
//Here is that I dont know what to do..

Comment: Good.  Please link to a pastebin of your form type and listener.  I can probably add in the magic lines of code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/9jVmw6bR ---> Listener
http://pastebin.com/0PBpKV56 ---> Type

Comment: Ok refreshed everything and it worked!, I didn't used the 'Choice' field type anyway because it kept saying that I had to pass an Object not a string.. Just a final question do I have to put the data transformer inside the createNamed as well as in the original formType? 

Btw. putting this answer as accepted :) THANK U again!!

Comment: Yep.  Put the same transformer in both.

Comment: This is a good solution. Although it doesn't work so well if validation fails and you need to redisplay the form.