# Symfony2: what is a "norm" data for a choice field type in forms

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm working on a Symfony2 project where I have three fields that are populated dynamically which mean are built by AJAX call made in Angular JS controller. So the problem is, when I send the form I get the message:

```
This value is not valid.
```

So after do a lot of research ([Symfony2 Nested Select in Spanish](http://showmethecode.es/php/symfony/symfony2-selects-dependientes-mediante-eventos/), [Dynamic Form Modification from Symfony2 Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html), [How to use Data Transformers from Symfony2 Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html), [Post here in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386867/symfony2-data-transformer-on-a-choice-field-type), [Entity as hidden field](http://lrotherfield.com/blog/symfony2-forms-entity-as-hidden-field/) and many more pages I read) I found "almost" nothing so here is my question: what is a "norm data" for a choice field type? This is what my Type returns:

```
public function getParent() {
    return 'choice';
}

public function getName() {
    return 'country_choice';
}
```

For some reason the validation fails all the time and I suspect is due to choice type and since I don't know what "norm data" is for a choice type I can't work in proper way on DataTransformer. Could any point me in the right direction? Any advice or help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on the choices you set. For example, if you have a field called 'my_field' with choices:

```
'choices' => array('m' => 'Male', 'f' => 'Female')
```

and you set the post data with value 0, the field will be invalid because its value is not in the choices list.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choices

Comment: You're right that's the cause but my question regarding this is where and how I populate that field, in which part?